# Show div class one by one

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

In blade.php file in Laravel I create a class name flip, when I click on it a class named panel is showed. Here $post_list contains some data which is collected from database table in previous controller. Using @for I can create many flip and slide class, but problem is when I click any of the flip class all slide class is showed. How can I click on one flip class and show the respective slide class?

Here is code for creating flip and panel class

```
@foreach($post_list as $post_list)
<div class="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div class="panel">
<ul>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" name="selected[]">
<label>
<img src="{{ URL::asset($post_list-->image)}}" />
<p>{{$post_list->id->name}}</p>
</label>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
@endforeach
```

And here is my javascript code -

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".flip").click(function(){
    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can try $(document).ready(function(){
$(".flip").click(function(){
    $(this).find(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
});
});

Answer (score 2):

You are toggling all `.panel` divs. You need to take only the required `.panel` in context.

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".flip").click(function(){
            $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I am new in js. I don't understand why you use next, Please explain it ...

Comment: `.next('.panel')` will select the element which is next to `this` element (i.e. `.flip` which is clicked) provided it has the class `panel` (the one passed as parameter to the `next` function). Read the jQuery API documentation for `next`

Comment: tell me if you didn't get what I said

Comment: Yes I got it . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(".flip").click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".panel").slideDown(500, function(){
         // do additional stuff here..
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click','.flip',function(){
    $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle("slow");
});
</script>
```